# How can I generate an internal URL to a CiviCRM page based on certain parameters?

Tags: developer

What functions exist within CiviCRM that make it easy for me to generate internal URLs?

Answer (score 4):

#### In PHP

```
CRM_Utils_System::url('civicrm/contact/view', "reset=1&cid=$contactID")
```

See code-level docs for `CRM_Utils_System::url` for more details.

#### In Smarty

```
{crmURL p='civicrm/contact/view' q="reset=1&cid=`$contactID`"}
```

See code-level docs for `CRM_Utils_System::url` for more details.

#### In Javascript

```
CRM.url('civicrm/contact/view', {"reset": 1, "cid": contactID});
```

See code-level docs in `civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js` for `CRM.url` for more details.

*This content was migrated here from the [Cheatsheet](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Cheatsheet) wiki page as part of the 2017 wiki content migration project.*